# "cc1: all warnings being treated as errors" when building GCC 7.3 from source

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

I'm trying to build gcc 7.3 from source, but every time getting this error (I figured it out by using *make* without *-j* flag):

`proc.c:1355:17: error: comparision between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Werror=sign-compare]`
`cc1: all warnings being treated as errors`

Things I've already tried:

- Configuring using this command:
  `../gcc-7.3.0/configure --prefix=/opt/gcc-7.3.0 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --program-suffix=-7.3 --disable-multilib --with-system-zlib --disable-werror`
- Configuring this way:
  `../gcc-7.3.0/configure --prefix=/opt/gcc-7.3.0 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --program-suffix=-7.3 --disable-multilib --with-system-zlib --disable-werror CFLAGS='-Wno-error'`
- Setting before using make:
  `CFLAGS='-Wno-error'`
- Using command:
  `make CFLAGS='-Wno-error' -j 8`
- Checking if there isn't any *-Werror* flag in *Makefile*
- Checking my environment variables

Nothing of these worked, every time I get this error. Before trying to make all of this I downloaded additional dependencies with *contrib/download_prerequisites*
and I think I have all of needed libraries. I didn't saw any other errors.

I'm using kali linux:
***5.18.0-kali7-amd64***

Comment: Why are you building gcc from source on Kali Linux, a distribution specifically used for pentesting and **not** for general use? (especially given that GCC 7.3 is over 4 years old)

Comment: You _could_ just open `proc.c` and fix line 1355. `if (stacksize < (uintptr)SIGSTKSZ)`. You are compiling a _very_ old version of GCC. `SIGSTKSZ` has changed since then.

Comment: @SuperStormer Because I'm using it for both. I don't think I need dual boot with multiple Linux distros, when Kali is almost same as Debian. That's why, its just easier for me. I need older GCC to build tensorflow from source with TensorRT 8 support - in docs they are using GCC 7.3, and my GCC 10 and 11 both fails even with necessary flag.

Comment: You can call make with the option "-d" to let it generate lots of debug output, to see where and potentially why the compiler is still called with "-Werror".